# How to build a url with array of query parameters using http get request

Tags: angular, postgresql, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass multiple values that I have selected in Supplier component and display the detail information in Supplier detail component.

I have to execute the query like below with selected vendors.

```
 select distinct 
asu.vendor_name,
asu.segment1 vendor_number,
asu.end_date_active,
asu.vendor_id
 from ap_suppliers asu, ap_supplier_sites_all ass
  where ass.org_id = 81
  and   ass.vendor_id = asu.vendor_id
  and  asu.vendor_id IN (123, 234, 456, 778)
     order by asu.vendor_name
```

### supplier component

```
supplierdetails() {
let selectedFileIds: string[] = [];
const options = {queryParams: {numbers:selectedFileIds } }
for (let item of this.selection.selected) {
  selectedFileIds.push(item.vendor_id);
}
console.log(options);
this.router.navigate(['/supplierdetails'], options);
```

}

### supplier Detail Component

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
// this.retrieveSupdetails(this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(() =>this.numbers.getAll('options'));
 //(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
}
```

### Supplier Details Component Service

```
getSupdetails(vendor_id:number[]) {
  if (!this.supdetdata) {
    this.supdetdata = this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/supplierdetails?vendor_id=${vendor_id}`).pipe(
        map((data:any) => data.data),
        publishReplay(1),
        refCount()
    );
   }
   return this.supdetdata;
```

}

### Supplier Details Service

```
 async function getSupplierDetails(vendor_id){
 
const rows = await db.query(
    `select distinct 
    asu.vendor_name,
    asu.segment1 vendor_number,
    asu.end_date_active,
    asu.vendor_id
from ap_suppliers asu, ap_supplier_sites_all ass
where ass.org_id = 81
and   ass.vendor_id = asu.vendor_id
and  asu.vendor_id IN ($1)
order by asu.vendor_name`, [vendor_id]
  );
     
  const data = helper.emptyOrRows(rows);

  return {
    data
  }
```

}

### Supplier Details Router

```
  const express = require("express");
  const router = express.Router();
  const supplierdetails = require("../services/supplierdetails");

  router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
   try {
  res.json(await supplierdetails.getSupplierDetails(req.query.vendor_id));
    } catch (err) {
  console.error(`Error while getting supplier details`, err.message);
     next(err);
    }
   });

  module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Ramki.

To pass query params in a url through angular routing, use the `queryParams` property.

```js
this.router.navigate(['supplierdetails'], {
      queryParams: { vendor_name: 'name', vendor_id: 1234 },
    });
```

and in the receiving component

```js
  queryParams?: { vendor_name: string; vendor_id: number };

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.queryParams = { ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams } as any;
  }
```

Does that answer your question?

Also, if you want to just create the url for passing to an api it's like this:

```js
  queryParams?: { vendor_name: string; vendor_id: number };

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.queryParams = { ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams } as any;
    const tree = this.router.createUrlTree([], {
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
    });
    const url = 'https://www.root.com' + this.router.serializeUrl(tree);
    // https://www.root.com/?vendor_name=name&vendor_id=1234
  }
```

Comment: Thank You Chris for you reply  !   I have pass only vendor id  with multiple values.

Comment: No problem, I added how to create the url on its own if you needed that to call an api.